# How to activate automatically the python virtual environment?

Tags: python, ubuntu-14.04

Hello i have two python installed on my pc python2.7.6 and python2.7.11 and i use the python2.7.11 as a virtual environment version. How can i automatically set my terminal to python2.7.11 upon restarting the device.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $PATH
```

this will print out your currently configured PATH. One of them will contain `python2.7.6`.

Remove it with `export PATH="new path here without the python folder"`
Run `which python` after activating the virtual environment. Add this path to `$PATH`

Example:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin/python"
```

Add the changes you did into `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile`. Else the commands you ran will only count for the current SSH session. `profile` is run at every new SSH session.